# Best python sorting algorithm to handle large numbers

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

What sorting algorithm should I use in Python, in order to sort a list of elements, where each element can have a large number of digits(like between 1 and 10^5)? And the number of elements in the list is also large(say 10^5).

Comment: Do you mean that the numbers are between 1 and 10^5 or that they have between 1 and 10^5 digits? If the latter, and your concern is that the list doesn't fit into memory, you'll want to look into [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an algorithm at all, in the sense of implementing one. Just use the list's `sort` method, i.e, `mylist.sort()`.